# pass text box array values into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a hidden text-box which is in for loop.(Codeigniter View File)

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name->file_name;?>" name="high_name[]" />
```

i want to pass this array values into my java script function. I dont know how to do it for array.

```
$(".button").click( function() {

var name =  document.getElementById('high_name[]').value; 
alert(name);

});
```

what i want is, get these  names and pass it to the another text-area's value.

```
<textarea>.....</textarea>
```

Comment: Run `foreach` loop to get all names

Comment: `var text_value = $('input[name="high_name[]"]').val();` then assign to `textarea`. `getElementById` doesn't make sense since that actually the `name` attribute

Comment: `var text_value = $('input[name="high_name[]"]').val();
alert(text_value);` doesn't work.. no alert..

Comment: it works its either you're pointing to the wrong element, or it has no value at all http://codepad.viper-7.com/2fDGJM, if this has many elements, use `$.each` like the one answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**NOTE**: I adjusted the HTML slightly. A class was added to the inputs and they were made `text` in stead of `hidden`. The `text` is for example purposes, see what is happening. The class because (as far as i know) not all browsers select elements with a array notation all that good.

```js
$(".button").click( function() {

   $('input.high_name').each(function(){ 
     
       var currentVal = $("#toHere").val();
       $("#toHere").val(currentVal + "\n" + $(this).val());
     
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Value1" name="high_name[]" class="high_name" />
<input type="text" value="Value2" name="high_name[]" class="high_name" />
<input type="text" value="Value3" name="high_name[]" class="high_name" />

<button class="button">Click me</button>

<textarea id="toHere"></textarea>
```

You might want to optimize the `\n` part. But that comes when you implement this example to your own needs

Comment: We don't know if the OP wants jQuery, since he says in javascript

Comment: Cheshire please look at the code example. I added it, because not all browsers correctly support the selection of elements with array notations AFAIK

Comment: Saw it late, sorry X.X, supposed you got the same code as the op

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that i did an adjustment. Tnx for the heads up

Comment: what to do if the hidden filed is a checkbox??

Comment: @KavinSmk depends on what you want to do with it. It works the same, only have to add a check to make sure to only add the checked items (http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) . Want an example?

Comment: i got it i use `$('input.high_name:checked').each(function(){ ` thanks a lot @mvbrakel

Comment: Indeed! That's it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: why we have set initilaly  `var currentVal = $("#toHere").val();` ??

Comment: I am just used to that. Store the value that you are about to override. No need for it though. You could just do it when setting.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById('high_name[]')` does not work since `high_name[]` is not the Id of the HTML element. Instead try this

```
var name = $('input[name="high_name[]"]').val();
$("#textarea_id").html(name);
```

> //ensure that jQuery is included